# Parallel merge in single thread mode very slow

Tags: c, algorithm, merge, parallel-processing

I have two sets of sorted elementes and want to merge them together in way so i can parallelize it later. I have a simple merge implementation that has data dependencies because it uses the maximum function and a first version of a parallelizable merge that uses binary search to find the rank and compute the index for a given value.

The getRank function returns the number of elements lower or equal than the given needle.

```
#define ATYPE int

int getRank(ATYPE needle, ATYPE *haystack, int size) {
    int low = 0, mid;
    int high = size - 1;
    int cmp;
    ATYPE midVal;

    while (low <= high) {
        mid = ((unsigned int) (low + high)) >> 1;
        midVal = haystack[mid];
        cmp = midVal - needle;

        if (cmp < 0) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else if (cmp > 0) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else {
            return mid; // key found
        }
    }

    return low; // key not found
}
```

The merge algorithms operates on the two sorted sets a, b and store the result into c.

```
void simpleMerge(ATYPE *a, int n, ATYPE *b, int m, ATYPE *c) {
    int i, l = 0, r = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n + m; i++) {
        if (l < n && (r == m || max(a[l], b[r]) == b[r])) {
            c[i] = a[l];
            l++;
        } else {
            c[i] = b[r];
            r++;
        }
    }
}

void merge(ATYPE *a, int n, ATYPE *b, int m, ATYPE *c) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c[i + getRank(a[i], b, m)] = a[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        c[i + getRank(b[i], a, n)] = b[i];
    }
}
```

The merge operation is very slow when having a lot of elements and still can be parallelized, but simpleMerge is always faster even though it can not be parallelized.

So my question now is, do you know any better approach for parallel merging and if so, can you point me to a direction or is my code just bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complexity of `simpleMerge` function:

`O(n + m)`

Complexity of `merge` function:

`O(n*logm + m*logn)`

Without having thought about this too much, my suggestion for parallelizing it, is to find a single value that's around the middle of each function, using something similar to the getRank function, and using simple merge from there. That can be `O(n + m + log m + log n) = O(n + m)` (even if you do a few, but constant amount of lookups to find a value around the middle).

Comment: You are right, thanks! I should split the parts into logical blocks and do simple merge on these!

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm used by the merge function is best by asymptotic analysis. The complexity is O(n+m). You cannot find a better algorithm since I/O takes O(n+m).